# Como fazer Integração Frontend com Java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, bootstrap, front-end

Sou iniciante em frontend.
Estou fazendo um sistema usando **html,bootstrap,javascript e jquery.**
Vou ter que fazer a integração com o **java**.
Gostaria de alguma orientação.Pois não sei por onde começar.
 Vou fazer algumas perguntas:

1. O que o programador java vai ter que me passar?
2. Como vou fazer essa integração?
3. O que vou precisar usar para integrar?
4. Existe algum exemplo que eu posso olhar para conseguir entender como funciona a integração?(se existirem exemplos em português fico mais grata)

Sou bem iniciante mesmo, gostaria de conseguir algumas orientações e dicas para conseguir fazer essa integração.

Comment: Basicamente o backend Java vai te fornecer um endpoint/webservice, que nada mais é do que uma coleção de URLs para você se comunicar com ele para enviar/receber os dados que sua aplicação precisa. Para saber exatamente como fazer isso, primeiro vc vai ter que ter esses dados em mãos para saber se é um SOAP, REST, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Geralmente aplicações web em Java são feitas através de Javabeans e JPA. 
Tens de construir uma boa camada de negócio, uns handlers para tratarem da informação entre camadas e na camada de apresentação tens o JPA que te possibilita ligar as tuas páginas web ao backend em Java. O formato destes ficheiros costuma ser .jsp. Mas porque queres integrar frontend com Java? É preciso ter boas bases de OO